# "Failed TCP accept: emfile" in Ejabberd

Tags: mysql, erlang, mariadb, ejabberd

I'm running Ejabberd 15.04 with Erlang/OTP 17 and using Ubuntu [64-bit] in all my 4 instances of EC2 Amazon, where I run ejabberd. Ejabberd was installed from source.

I've configured it with 65,535 file descriptors and the following configuration:

ERL_MAX_PORTS=360,000

ERL_PROCESSES=15,000,000

ERL_MAX_ETS_TABLES=100,000

The thing is that suddenly, the servers stopped working and I found this in the logs, hundreds of times:

*2016-05-09 13:22:45.901 [error] <0.397.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:317 (#Port<0.4197>) Failed TCP accept: emfile*

I have made my own modules and run ejabberd in a cluster of 4 erlang nodes, behind an Elastic Load Balancer (of amazon). The machines have 4 cores and 30GB ram each. **I've migrated roster module to ODBC (MariaDB, similar to mysql)**. And 80k users are connected concurrently.

**I think that the file descriptors are high enough and erlang processes and ports too.
The error appeared suddenly, the servers worked fine for 3 weeks. Maybe the cause has to do with mysql? If you please know what the cause may be, I would be very greatful.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: set   nofile( max number of open files)  in  # /etc/security/limits.conf

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase limit of open file descriptors, you can get current maximum in Erlang by:

```
proplists:get_value(max_fds, erlang:system_info(check_io)).
```

If It's not same as the value set in OS and your software being started by an upstart script, make sure you set file descriptor limit in upstart script by using [limit stanza](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#limit):

```
limit nofile 65535 65535
```

Comment: I've checked that and it's alright. The problem persists.